# Fibre preserving maps of Borel constructions

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, fibre-bundles, equivariant-homotopy

Let $G$ be a discrete group with universal principal bundle $EG\to BG$, and let $X$ and $Y$ be left $G$-spaces. An equivariant map $\overline{f}:X\to Y$ induces a fibre-preserving map $f:EG\times_G X\to EG\times_G Y$ between Borel constructions, as in the following diagram.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    X @>\overline{f}>> Y\\
    @V  V V @VV V\\
    EG\times_G X  @>>f> EG\times_G Y \\
     @V  V V @VV V\\
    BG @>=>> BG
\end{CD}

I believe some sort of converse to be true. That is, if $f:EG\times_G X\to EG\times_G Y$ is a fibre-preserving map between Borel constructions, it induces a $G$-equivariant map $\overline{f}:X\to Y$. Here I am identifying $G=\pi_1(BG,\ast)$, which acts (up to homotopy) on the fibres.

> Does anyone know of a reference to a precise statement along these lines?

**Edit** (in response to user51223's comment): I'm mainly interested in the existence question: Is it true that there exists an equivariant map $\overline{f}:X\to Y$ if and only if there exists a map $f:EG\times_G X\to EG\times_G Y$ over $BG$? (So $\overline{f}$ doesn't have to be the induced map on fibres.)

Comment: I don't have an answer ready, but I believe it is a bit more complicated. Take $X$ and $Y$ to be vector spaces for simplicity, then $f$ is just a linear map between (locally trivial) vector bundles. Even if $\operatorname{Hom}_G(X,Y)$ is trivial, I don't see why $f$ should be zero everywhere.

Comment: @SebastianGoette: I'm trying to better understand your comment. Let's say $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$ with $X$ the trivial (1-dimensional) representation and $Y$ the sign representation. Then $\operatorname{Hom}_G(X,Y)=0$. Are there any non-zero bundle maps from the trivial line bundle to the non-trivial line bundle over $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$?

Comment: I think that the map from X to Y is in general only coherently homotopy equivariant. Have a look at Dror,Dwyer and Kan, Equivariant maps which are self homotopy equivalences, Propositions 2.2 and 2.3 (this paper is available on Bill Dwyer's webpage).

Comment: Dear Mark, you can certainly cook up a map that is not everywhere $0$ using a partition of unity, assuming the base field contains $\mathbb R$. But then on the other hand, the space of linear maps is typically contractible.  I guess Gustavo's comment is more to the point.

Comment: That $f$ always induces $\overline{f}$ is a fact right? And, your question is that if this map is $G$-equivariant? Or are you looking for any $G$-equivariant map that possible induced by $f$?

Comment: @GustavoGranja: This is really helpful, thanks. After reading their 2.3 I realised that $f$ induces a $G$-map $EG\times X\to EG\times Y$ (which is obvious from covering space theory). Is this what is meant by "coherently homotopy equivariant"?

Comment: @user51223: I'm interested in both versions of the question (hence the "along these lines"), but only really need the weaker existence question. I've edited to make this clear.

Comment: @MarkGrant You are very welcome. By coherently equivariant homotopic I meant extending to a homotopy coherent map of diagrams indexed by the category $G$ with one object (and $G$ as the monoid of endomorphisms). I think this is equivalent to the map extending to $EG \times X \to Y$ as $EG\times X \to X$ is a cofibrant replacement for the diagram $X$. Note that since $EG$ is a terminal object in the homotopy category of free $G$-spaces giving a $G$-equivariant map from $EG\times X \to EG \times Y$ is really the same as giving a $G$-equivariant map form $EG \times X \to Y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question in the edit is no. Take $G=\mathbb Z$, $X$ to be a point and $Y=\mathbb R$ with the action $n\cdot x = x+n$. Then there are no equivariant maps from $X$ to $Y$ but there are many maps from $EG \times_G X = BG = S^1$ to the cylinder $EG \times_G Y$ over $BG$.

In this special case when $X$ is a point, an equivariant map $X \to Y$ is a fixed point, while a map $EG \times_G X \to EG \times_G Y$ is a homotopy fixed point. The fixed points include in the homotopy fixed points, but in general I don't think there is much one can say about the inclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Granja's answer: let $X$ be a point, and $Y = EG$, and let $f$ be induced by the diagonal on $EG$.